# Executing code before loading the UI

Tags: json, swift

I have just started learning Swift and I am trying to get a Json array to be displayed in a table view.

After a few hours of debugging I realized that the data was not ready by the time the UI appears as I get a `numberOfRowsInSection = 0`

I was wondering if there was a way to load the table after the Json data has been pulled from the URL.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, NSURLConnectionDelegate  {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    lazy var data = NSMutableData()
    var datatodisplay = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    startConnection()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    println(datatodisplay.count)
    return datatodisplay.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel?.text = datatodisplay[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

  func startConnection(){
    //start connection to the the fixer.io API
    let urlPath: String = "http://api.fixer.io/latest"
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)!
    connection.start()
}  

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
    var rawdata = jsonResult
    println(rawdata)
    dezarray(rawdata)
}

func dezarray(rawdata: NSDictionary){

    if let rawrates = rawdata["rates"] as? NSDictionary {
        println(rawrates)
        println((rawrates.count))
        println(rawrates["USD"])
        for (currency, rawrate) in rawrates {
            println("\(currency): \(rawrate)")
            datatodisplay.append("\(currency): \(rawrate)")
        }

        println(datatodisplay)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download your data from the internet it's pretty common that you don't have the data when you first display your UI.

This is easy to fix. Let the table view display as empty at first. Then just call `tableView.reloadData()` at the end of your `connectionDidFinishLoading` method. The tableview will then ask for the number of sections and rows, and repopulate itself with the data that has just finished loading.

You can display a UIProgressIndicator on top of the table view while it's downloading if you want to let the user know that they need to wait for the data to download. You might also want to disable the UI if the user can click buttons that crash if there is no data.

Sometimes I'll overlay the entire view controller's content view with a 50% opaque black view that contains a progress indicator. The view prevents the user from clicking on anything and dims the view at the same time. Then when the slow task is complete I'll simply hide the translucent black view.

Comment: So post the code that gives that error, along with the declarations of all the variables/structs/etc that are referenced in the offending line.